# Problem with if-statement and whereClause format

Tags: arcpy, sql, parameters, where-clause

I have a program which should count the number of a feature class or the length of a feature class depending on the geometry of the input feature class. This part is working.
There are two parameter-fields. One dropdown-field (optional) where you can choose a fieldname of the feature class and the other is a parameter field (optional) where you can choose a value depending on the fieldname which was chosen.
If I put in values in both optional parameter fields, the number or the length of the feature class should be count by using the inputvalues in a SQL-expression (whereClause).
If I am trying to do that, I get following error:
IndexError: tuple index out of range
in line:

```
whereClause = whereClause.format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(fc_clipped, fieldname))
```

Second problem:
Why are both fields optional? Because if I don't put in any value to both optional parameters, the number of the feature class should be count (without a whereClause) with GetCountManagement.
But the code is still running through the else-statement and I get an error because of leaving the fieldname-parameter empty even though the parameter is optional.

So what I need is that the SQL-Expressions works with the input-parameters and
if the input-parameters are empty it should just use the GetCountManagement.

That is the full code:

```
    fc_clipped = os.path.join(out_gebietsscharfe_Objekte, objektname)+"_"+gebietsname #input feature
    fn = parameters[2].valueAsText #fieldname

    if arcpy.Describe(fc_clipped).shapeType == "Point" or "Polygon":
        if parameters[2].valueAsText == "#":
            COUNTER = arcpy.GetCount_management(fc_clipped)
        else:
            COUNTER = 0
            whereClause = """{} = '{}'"""
            whereClause = whereClause.format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(fc_clipped, fn))
            for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc_clipped, fn, whereClause):
                COUNTER+=1
    else:
        fn = "Shape_Length"
        COUNTER = 0
        whereClause = """{} = '{}'"""
        whereClause = whereClause.format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(fc_clipped, fn))
        for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc_clipped, fn, whereClause):
            COUNTER+=row[0]

    arcpy.AddMessage(COUNTER)
```

Comment: Normally SQL 'OR' requieres you to write: if arcpy.Describe(fc_clipped).shapeType == "Point" OR arcpy.Describe(fc_clipped).shapeType == "Polygon"

Comment: @blabbath Thanks for your response but that is not the issue in the program. It works with 'or'

Comment: No, it doesn't. You need to be careful with Boolean expressions in Python, because `or nonZero` will always result in True. @blabbath is correct

Comment: `arcpy.Describe(fc_clipped).shapeType == "Point" or "Polygon"` will always return `True`.  If you had a line feature class, it would return `True`. You need `arcpy.Describe(fc_clipped).shapeType == "Point" or `arcpy.Describe(fc_clipped).shapeType == "Polygon"` OR `arcpy.Describe(fc_clipped).shapeType in ("Point" , "Polygon")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @blabbath has mentioned this line of code isn't doing what you'd like it to do:

`if arcpy.Describe(fc_clipped).shapeType == "Point" or "Polygon":`

This statement will always return `True` regardless of what `arcpy.Describe(fc_clipped).shapeType` returns:

```
>>> if 1 + 7 == 50 or 12:
    print "hello world"


hello world
```

Think of it like this:

`if (1 + 7 == 50) OR (12)`

1 + 7 does not equal 50, but 12 returns `True`.

Alternatives:

```
>>> if 1 + 7 == 50 or 1 + 7 == 12:
    print "hello world"


>>> if 1 + 7 in (50, 12):
    print "hello world"


>>>
```

Your fix:

`if arcpy.Describe(fc_clipped).shapeType in ("Point", "Polygon"):`

Comment: Yes, you are all right with it. Thank you!

Comment: This is because non-empty strings are "Truthy".